# slurm sbatch --output and --error flags ignored

Tags: slurm, sbatch

i'm currently using slurm in my project, and am trying to run an very simple hello world job. I want to redirect my stdout and errorout to an specific file in an specific location. Therefore I used the following command: `sudo su -c 'sbatch /home/slurm/job.script --error=/home/slurm/job%j.out --output=/home/slurm/job%j.out' slurm`. But I am ignored completely. He just tries (and fails because he has no permission) to create a file where the command is issued.
Im using a Debian 10 vagrant box. And my slurm version is slurm-wlm 18.08.5-2 (output from sinfo -V)

slurm job file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --time=1
srun -l /bin/hostname
srun -l /bin/pwd
srun -l echo "hello world"
```

slurm conf file:

```
ClusterName=slurm_cluster  # By default ClusterName=linux
ControlMachine=Kitsune
ControlAddr=172.16.0.20
#
SlurmUser=slurm
SlurmdUser=slurm
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPort=6818
AuthType=auth/munge
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurm/ctld
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurm/d
SwitchType=switch/none
MpiDefault=none
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurm/slurmctld.pid
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurm/slurmd.pid
ProctrackType=proctrack/pgid
ReturnToService=0

# TIMERS
SlurmctldTimeout=300
SlurmdTimeout=300
InactiveLimit=0
MinJobAge=300
KillWait=30
Waittime=0
#

DebugFlags=NO_CONF_HASH
# LOGGING
SlurmctldDebug=3
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=3
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
#
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=worker1 NodeAddr=172.16.0.21 Port=6818 Procs=1 State=UNKNOWN
#NodeName=worker2 NodeAddr=172.16.0.22 Port=6818 Procs=1 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=debug Nodes=ALL Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware that writing

```
sbatch /home/slurm/job.script --error=/home/slurm/job%j.out --output=/home/slurm/job%j.out
```

assumes `--error` and `--output` are parameters to `job.script`. Try

```
sbatch --error=/home/slurm/job%j.out --output=/home/slurm/job%j.out /home/slurm/job.script
```

Comment: Ah yes i missed that... thanks for your help